# Google Charts and JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm not a JS guy, I working on a small interface for my weather station. I have a serverside code which generates the JSON data for the graph. It looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "temperature": "32.1",
    "humidity": "91",
    "battery": "100",
    "time": "2016-02-21 15:28:56"
  },
  {
    "temperature": "32.1",
    "humidity": "99.3",
    "battery": "100",
    "time": "2016-02-21 15:28:47"
  },
  {
    "temperature": "22.2",
    "humidity": "70.2",
    "battery": "88.2",
    "time": "2016-02-21 15:28:19"
  },
  {
    "temperature": "21.2",
    "humidity": "88.1",
    "battery": "90.4",
    "time": "2016-02-21 15:28:22"
  }
]
```

How can I feed this data into a Line chart using Google's Chart API? I have tried using the example but it does not work. (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define your array in the format which google charts requires:

```
$resultsarray = array(
                    'cols' => array(
                                    array('label' => 'temperature', 'type' => 'number'),
                                    array('label' => 'humidity', 'type' => 'number'),
                                    array('label' => 'battery', 'type' => 'number'),
                                    array('label' => 'time', 'type' => 'date'),
                                        ),
                    'rows' => array()
                    );
```

Then add the data to your array:

```
$resultsarray['rows'][] = array('c' => array( array('v'=> 'tempvalue'), array('v'=>'humidityval'), array('v'=>'batteryval'),array('v'=>'timeval')));
```

Encode as JSON and write to a file:

```
$fp = fopen('data.json', 'w');

    //JSON encode and write array to file
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($resultsarray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
    fclose($fp);
```

Then in your JavaScript you need: (as per [Google Example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example))

```
    function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "getData.php",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

Then the contents of getdata.php (as per google example)

```
<?php 

// This is just an example of reading server side data and sending it to the client.
// It reads a json formatted text file and outputs it.

$string = file_get_contents("data.json");
echo $string;

// Instead you can query your database and parse into JSON etc etc

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The json isn't formatted properly. Google charts expect a specific json type for its chart. I'm assuming that your database is mysql. If not, I can always modify the following code. I have created a small library to perform these annoying tasks. So here it is :

```
<?php


function generate_GChart_cols($result) {

    $fieldcount = mysqli_num_fields($result);
    $stringVal = [253]; // MySQL field type codes -See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php
    $numericVal = [246, 8];  // MySQL field type codes -See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php
    $colsarray = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $fieldcount; $i++) {
        $finfo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i);
        switch ($finfo->type) {
        case in_array($finfo->type, $stringVal):
            $type = 'string';
            break;

        case in_array($finfo->type, $numericVal):
            $type = 'number';
            break;

        default:
            $type = 'string';
        }

        // Constructs the column array

        $colsarray[] = array(
            'label' => $finfo->name,
            'type' => $type
        );
    }

    return $colsarray;
}



function generate_GChart_rows($result) {

    $fieldcount = mysqli_num_fields($result);
    $rows = array();

    while ($r = $result->fetch_row()) {

        $temp = array();

        for ($j = 0; $j < $fieldcount; $j++) {            

            $temp[] = array(
                'v' => $r[$j]
            );
        }

        $rows[] = array(
            'c' => $temp
        );
    };
    return $rows;
}

?>
```

A usage example would be :

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*'); //Include this header to make the requests cross-origin
include 'dbconnect.php';
include 'generate_google_json.php';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = // Your query here - e.g SELECT * FROM TABLE // ;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$table['data']['rows'] = generate_GChart_rows($result); // Call to function to generate rows
$table['data']['cols'] = generate_GChart_cols($result); // Call to function to generate columns
$conn->close(); // Close db connection

// We echo the json and enforce a numeric check on the values

echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($table, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) . ')';
?>
```

An example output would be :

```
?(
    {  
      data:{  
          rows:[  
             {  
                c:[  
                   {  
                      v:3123600
                   },
                   {  
                      v:3116452
                   }
                ]
             }
          ],
          cols:[  
             {  
                label:2013,
                type:"number"
             },
             {  
                label:2014,
                type:"number"
             }
          ]
       }
    }
)
```

In the event where you use other types than bigint, varchart and decimal, you might wanna add more values to the $stringVal and $numericVal arrays :)

Cheers

Comment: I like this, nice job. I've recently stopped using google, and now use NVD3 charts extension to D3, you can do what you want with them then its its reasonably easy to setup if you know JS

Comment: I have tried many libraries too, but I think that the one with the most consistent data format is google. Other libraries are nice too, but you always end up with a ton of boilerplate code when trying to construct the data. In my case, with my library, I can do that for any query in < 20 lines of code ^^, and the great thing is that it offers a great layer of abstraction.

Answer (score -1):

Google charts is expecting the JSON in this format:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"temperature","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"humidity","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"battery","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"time","pattern":"","type":"date"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"32.1","f":null},{"v":99.3,"f":null},{"v":100,"f":null},{"v":2016-02-21 15:28:47,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```